# Validate API key before calling database

Tags: rest

When designing an API, is it worth validating the API key before checking the database to see whether or not the key is valid?

For instance, the key could look like this: `key$hash`

If the `hash` doesn't match the `key`, one would know that the key is invalid from the get-go.

Comment: What benefit do you see? What would make this worth it for you?

Comment: Do you want to save database calls? Better developer experience?

Comment: Save database calls. I'm thinking people without API keys might spam the service (can't even cache the API keys as invalid because people can make up random keys) but people with API keys can easily be rate limited

Comment: You should try to figure out what level of (malicious?) traffic you want to support, measure and figure out where your bottlenecks are. If you have *no idea* about any of this, you probably shouldn't invest too much time in it yet.